# Cesium material being ignored on polygon

Tags: angular, cesiumjs

I am trying to set the colour of a polygon using the material property, like this:

```
drawOnMap() {
  let material = Cesium.Material.fromType('Color');
  material.uniforms.color = new Cesium.Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  const entityObject = {
    polygon: {
      hierarchy: this.positions !== undefined ? this.positions : undefined,
      height: 0,
      material: material, 
    }
  };

  return this.cesiumEntity = this.cesiumViewerService.getViewer().entities.add( entityObject );
}
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations to create the material, but they are all being ignored and the polygon is being rendered as white. What am I missing?

Note that if I use `Cesium.Color.RED`, the polygon renders as red, as expected.

Help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got two different APIs in use here.  After an Entity has been created, you can edit an existing Material by setting color uniforms and such.  But, before the entity exists, the fields you use are for the Entity creation options, not for the pre-existing Entity.

So looking at the [Entity](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/Entity.html) doc, we can see an option `polygon` that takes a [PolygonGraphics](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolygonGraphics.html), which has a field `material` that takes a [MaterialProperty](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/MaterialProperty.html) (not a constructed material!), which is an abstract class with a few implementations, one of which is [ColorMaterialProperty](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/ColorMaterialProperty.html).

So, try this:

```
drawOnMap() {
  let materialProperty = new Cesium.ColorMaterialProperty(
      new Cesium.Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
  );

  const entityObject = {
    polygon: {
      hierarchy: this.positions !== undefined ? this.positions : undefined,
      height: 0,
      material: materialProperty
    }
  };

  return this.cesiumEntity = this.cesiumViewerService.getViewer().entities.add( entityObject );
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but now the polygon comes out black! No matter what arguments I pass to the `Color` contructor

Comment: Yes, worked it out. I was using the range 0-255 to specify the value for each channel, not 0-1. Where can I find out more about the differences between the two APIs, and about material and all that stuff? Didn't quite understand your explanation of the pre- and post-entity creation stuff.

Comment: Compare what `entityObject` is in your code above, to what `this.cesiumEntity` becomes at the bottom.  The latter is a constructed `instanceof Cesuim.Entity`, but the former is just a giant options object being passed in for construction.  The construction happens implicitly in the `entities.add` call at the bottom of this code.  Cesium prefers to construct them itself rather than having you call `new Entity` manually, but all the constructor options shown in the docs are what `add` is passing into the new entity.